# How many finite integer groups are there?

Tags: group-theory, integers

I have got an assignment which has a question that asks us to write a program which can decide whether or not the input entered is a group or not. Now I know that the set of integers is a group on the addition operation, but that is infinite. The only finite integer group I can think of is the integers mod n. Are there any other finite groups having integer elements?

Comment: I’m not sure that $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ qualifies as an “integer group”, since this is not a term in my mathematical vocabulary. Why don’t you consider multiplication?

Comment: Well, if you are disregarding isomorphism, I could certainly consider multiplicative finite integer groups.

Comment: @Lubin by integer group I meant the groups which only have integer elements. Is it necessary that such groups contain all the integers from 0 to N?

Comment: how is the operation defined? You can't say if something is a group without this

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo as I only want integer elements, how about only addition and multiplication?

Comment: Note that integers modulo $n$ are not integers, but classes representing integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only finite subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ under addition is $\{0\}$ because all other elements have infinite order.

The only subset of $\mathbb Z$ that becomes a group under multiplication is $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ and $\{1,-1\}$.

First notice that no element other than $0,1$ and $-1$ can be present because they have infinite order.

Now notice that a subset including $0$ must only contain $0$ because otherwise the left multiplication won't be injective.

And then check the $3$ options that contain $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Is Z/n not a finite group under addition or multiplication?

Comment: Honestly the question itself is weird, because no one cares about what the elements in a group are, they just care about the structure of the group.

Comment: I know, I am not very well versed with abstract algebra, but I am trying to find the solution with whatever knowledge I have. I care about the elements in the group as I have to take them from the user. I don't want to input any weird permutations or complex numbers, I just want to take integers. That's why I wanted to know the kinds of finite groups having integer elements so that I can print the correct output.

Comment: But what do you real want by "printing the correct output"? What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The question given to us in the assignment is very vague. That's the reason I am having problems. So I only want to input a group of integers and then check if it is a group or not so that the program doesn't get too messy. So if the user enters a set of integers with a particular operation, namely addition or multiplication, I just want to print out if the given set forms a group for that particular operation.